# Checking value in form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I found this function and it works fine. But now it adds the class to the field while typing in it. I want to add the class to it after clicking on something else on the page. Also it adds the class to the fields after filling all the fields but I want to add it to each field separately after filling one field.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.av-extra-cookie-btn').attr('target', '_blank'); 
    });

    $('.gform_fields .medium').focusout(function(){

        var empty = false;
        $('.gform_fields .medium').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('.gfield_label').removeClass( "correct" );
        } else {
            $('.gfield_label').addClass( "correct" );
        }
    });



})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your logic works on `keyup`, which is why it happens as you type. Also, you set `empty` within the loop but use it *outside* the loop so only the last element's state will be recognised. It would help to see your HTML  here too

Comment: This is my HTML
https://www.codepile.net/pile/7m7AKkpN

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
(function($) {

  $('.gform_fields .medium').blur(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == '') {

    $(this).closest('li').find('.gfield_label').addClass('correct');
        }

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Instead of my whole function? I tried it but doesn't work for me

Comment: Updated my answer try this.

Comment: Doesn't work. I am having this code right now (see modified code).
It checks all the fields before adding validation to it but it needs to be done after filling one field